# WHy does this code crash, when used with bin?

Tags: c, binary, crash, converters

As the title suggests, I don't know where my mistake is with binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char binary[360];

void printstringasbinary(char* s)
{
    // A small 9 characters buffer we use to perform the conversion
    char output[9];

    while (*s)
    {
        // Convert the first character of the string to binary using itoa.
        // Characters in c are just 8 bit integers, at least, in noawdays computers.

        itoa(*s, output, 2);

        strcat(binary, output);

        ++s;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i, n;

    //printf("argc: %i\n", argc);
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        puts("Converter [Text] [hex|dec|bin]");
        return 0;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen("Output.txt", "a");
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[0]); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "hex") == 0)
            fprintf(f, "%X ", (unsigned int) argv[1][i]);
        else if (strcmp(argv[2], "dec") == 0)
            fprintf(f, "%i ", (unsigned int) argv[1][i]);
        else if (strcmp(argv[2], "bin") == 0)
            for (n = 0; n < strlen(argv[1]); n++)
            {
                printstringasbinary(argv[1][i]);
            }
        fprintf(f, "%s ", binary);

    }
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code, does not post it!

Comment: Please visit the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center. Questions must be entirely self contained.

Comment: `printstringasbinary(argv[1][i]);` ---> `printstringasbinary(argv[1]);`

Comment: @LPs: looks strange; but I suppose it's not the reason for the crash, right?

Comment: @StephanLechner It is indeed. The`printstringasbinary` function wants a char pointer while `argv[1][i]` passes a char. So OP has to decide if the function called must "parse" the string or if the for loop inside the main passes all chars one by one.

Comment: @OP: If the compiler screams during compilation you should listen to it. Besides that you iterate over the length of your program name and use the counter as index to your first command line parameter. This might be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate through the characters of `argv[1][i]`, whereas `i` can take on values up to the string length of `argv[0]`. Depending on whether `argv[0]` is "longer" than `argv[1]`, this can lead to a seg fault.
Did you mean `printstringasbinary(argv[1][n])` instead of `printstringasbinary(argv[1][i])`? BTW: why - as pointed out by LPs - do you iterate through `argv[1]` at all?

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[0]); i++)
....

        for (n = 0; n < strlen(argv[1]); n++)
        {
            printstringasbinary(argv[1][n]);
        }
```